# Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : NA/NaN/Inf in 'y', tried every possible way

Tags: r, nan, logistic-regression, na, lm

Here my dataset is `pd` and i have split it into training and testing data as `pd_train1` and `pd_train2`

```
    sku national_inv lead_time in_transit_qty forecast_3_month forecast_6_month
1 3921548            8        12              0                0                0
2 3191009           83         2             33              157              377
3 2935810            8         4              0                0                0
4 2205847           31         4             63               70              160
5 4953497            3        12              0                0                0
6 2286884            0         8              0                0                0
  forecast_9_month sales_1_month sales_3_month sales_6_month sales_9_month min_bank
1                0             1             1             2             5        2
2              603            44            98           148           156       53
3                0             0             0             1             1        0
4              223            27            90           164           219        0
5                0             0             0             0             0        0
6                0             0             0             0             0        0
  potential_issue pieces_past_due perf_6_month_avg perf_12_month_avg local_bo_qty
1               0               0             0.63              0.75            0
2               0               0             0.68              0.66            0
3               0               0             0.73              0.78            0
4               0               0             0.73              0.78            0
5               0               0             0.81              0.74            0
6               0               0             0.91              0.96            0
  deck_risk oe_constraint ppap_risk stop_auto_buy rev_stop went_on_backorder  data
1         0             0         0             1        0                No train
2         0             0         0             1        0                No train
3         0             0         0             1        0                No train
4         0             0         1             1        0                No train
5         0             0         0             1        0                No train
6         0             0         0             1        0                No train
```

I wanted to create a lm model for my training data `pd_train1`
But i am getting this error as below:

```
> fit=lm(went_on_backorder~.,data=pd_train1)
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'
In addition: Warning message:
In storage.mode(v) <- "double" : NAs introduced by coercion
```

I tried searching for infinite values:

```
sapply(pd_train1, function(x) sum(is.infinite(x)))
             sku      national_inv         lead_time    in_transit_qty  forecast_3_month 
                0                 0                 0                 0                 0 
 forecast_6_month  forecast_9_month     sales_1_month     sales_3_month     sales_6_month 
                0                 0                 0                 0                 0 
    sales_9_month          min_bank   potential_issue   pieces_past_due  perf_6_month_avg 
                0                 0                 0                 0                 0 
perf_12_month_avg      local_bo_qty         deck_risk     oe_constraint         ppap_risk 
                0                 0                 0                 0                 0 
    stop_auto_buy          rev_stop went_on_backorder              data 
                0                 0                 0                 0
```

And also for NA/NaN values in my training data on which i want to make linear model

```
     sku      national_inv         lead_time    in_transit_qty  forecast_3_month 
                0                 0                 0                 0                 0 
 forecast_6_month  forecast_9_month     sales_1_month     sales_3_month     sales_6_month 
                0                 0                 0                 0                 0 
    sales_9_month          min_bank   potential_issue   pieces_past_due  perf_6_month_avg 
                0                 0                 0                 0                 0 
perf_12_month_avg      local_bo_qty         deck_risk     oe_constraint         ppap_risk 
                0                 0                 0                 0                 0 
    stop_auto_buy          rev_stop went_on_backorder 
                0                 0                 0 


Inf %in% pd_train1$went_on_backorder
1] FALSE

NaN %in% pd_test$went_on_backorder
1] FALSE
```

Henceforth I am not able to get the NA/NaN/Inf values in my dataset
Can someone help me understand why is this throwing an error, please?
Here `went_on_backorder` is my target variable.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? How many data points are you using in the modeling?

Comment: there are around 250078 datapoints, how can i provide a reproducible example any idea?, and i didnt understand what did u actually edit?

Comment: Ideally you would simulate a dataset that would produce the error at hand. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for some ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The column `went_on_backorder` is a factor. Linear regression requires a numeric response variable.

To use logistic regression, use `glm` in base R or a package such as `vgam`. Here's a brief example:

```
pd_train1 <- data.frame('went_on_backorder' = c('No','Yes','Yes'), 'lead_time' = 1:3)
model <- glm(went_on_backorder ~ ., data = pd_train1, family = 'binomial')
```

And you can predict your classes:

```
predict(model, newdata = data.frame('lead_time' = c(0,1,2.5,3.5)), type = "response")
```

Answer (score 1):

`went_on_backorder` is not a numeric variable. `lm` cannot deal with non-numeric dependent variables. Look into [logistic regression](https://towardsdatascience.com/simply-explained-logistic-regression-with-example-in-r-b919acb1d6b3).